# Error sending payment transaction on mina devnet

Tags: node.js, blockchain, apache-mina

I'm trying to sign and send a mina transaction on devnet and it fails with this message.

```
error - Error: Query failed -- returned code 200. mutation($from:PublicKey!, $to:PublicKey!, $amount:UInt64!, $fee:UInt64!, $memo:String, $scalar:String, $field:String, $nonce:UInt32){ sendPayment(input: { from:$from, to:$to, amount:$amount, fee:$fee, memo:$memo, nonce:$nonce }, signature:{ scalar: $scalar, field: $field, }) { payment { amount fee feePayer { publicKey token } feeToken from fromAccount { publicKey token } hash id isDelegation kind memo nonce receiver { publicKey token } source { publicKey token } to token toAccount { token publicKey } } } } | {'data': None, 'errors': [{'message': 'Couldn\'t send user_command: Error creating user command: {"payload":{"common":{"fee":"0.01","fee_token":"1","fee_payer_pk":"B62qqAMY1gz8kvEAyf1ioBLPCfbq8WqpLqGXTqUF9LBVf4HLSTXTnMb","nonce":"0","valid_until":"4294967295","memo":"E4YM2vTHhWEg66xpj52JErHUBU4pZ1yageL4TVDDpTTSsv8mK6YaH"},"body":["Payment",{"source_pk":"B62qqAMY1gz8kvEAyf1ioBLPCfbq8WqpLqGXTqUF9LBVf4HLSTXTnMb","receiver_pk":"B62qop7Eh2nAymEun27TJYhKA1rWyvGHgHGwFpQDF1ANhFt2zCqsVFU","token_id":"1","amount":"1"}]},"signer":"B62qqAMY1gz8kvEAyf1ioBLPCfbq8WqpLqGXTqUF9LBVf4HLSTXTnMb","signature":["Signature","7mX8NLNR3mWuEV7QvQi5Z7yEfJn13y3KNS9BBHo9B31UuMhzBm9G3jKKMXpMY1Lr6obrP9BfP92KfVxDfsoBwiDV93kT17Lg"]} Error: Invalid_signature', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 136}], 'path': ['sendPayment']}]}
```

This is the transfer function and it fails at when I send it to `/broadcast/tx` endpoint `fetch...` call.
Thank you.

```js
const transfer2 = async (sender: string, receiver: string, amount: number) => {

...
  let signedPayment = MinaSDK.signPayment({
    to: receiver,
    from: sender,
    amount: 1,
    fee: 10000000,
    nonce: json.account.nonce
  }, keys);

  res = await fetch(process.env.MINA_REST_URL! + '/broadcast/transaction', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(signedPayment),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })

  json = await res.json()
  if (res.status !== 200) {
    throw new Error(json.error)
  }

  return json

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and for further reference there is the transfer function, I used to send MINA on devnet.

```js
const minaGqlClient = new GraphQLClient(process.env.MINA_GRAPHQL_URL!)
// MINA_GRAPHQL_URL="https://devnet.graphql.minaexplorer.com/"

const transfer = async (sender: string, receiver: string, _amount: number) => {

  let amount =  new BigNumber(_amount).multipliedBy(1000000000).toFixed(0)
  // get account details
  let res = await fetch(process.env.MINA_REST_URL! + '/accounts/' + sender)
  let json = await res.json()

  let keys = {
    publicKey: process.env.MINA_GAME_WALLET_PUBLIC_KEY!,
    privateKey: process.env.MINA_GAME_WALLET_PRIVATE_KEY!,
  }

  let signedPayment = minaSignerClient.signPayment({
    to: receiver,
    from: sender,
    amount: amount,
    fee: BigNumber("0.06").multipliedBy(1000000000).toString(),
    nonce: json.account.nonce,
  }, keys.privateKey)

  const isPaymentVerified = minaSignerClient.verifyPayment(signedPayment)

  if (!isPaymentVerified) {
    throw new Error("Payment signature is not valid")
  }

  json = {
    ...signedPayment,
    payload: signedPayment.data,
  }

  delete json.data

  console.info("Signed payment: ", JSON.stringify(signedPayment, null, 2))

  res = await fetch(process.env.MINA_REST_URL! + '/broadcast/transaction', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(json),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })

  json = await res.json()
  if (res.status != 201) {
    throw new Error(json.error)
  }

  return json
}
```